# How do I log Socket.io through Winston?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, winston

I would like to use Winston as logger for Socket.io. I have seen [this issue](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/800) where it says:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);
io.set('logger', { debug: <log function>, info: … , error: .., warn: .. })
```

Unfortunately, it is not described what the `log function` should look like.

Some playing around and a look into the [Socket.io logger documentation](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/blob/0.9.14/lib/logger.js) told me that there is no fixed set of parameters: There are log messages with one, two and three parameters. Perhaps there are even more, I don't know.

I think that this is definitely not a good practice to have an undefined number of parameters, especially if this is your interface to external components.

Anyway ... does anybody have some experience with this? Can anyone point out what to watch out for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to work fine for me

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server, {
    logger: {
        debug: winston.debug, 
        info: winston.info, 
        error: winston.error, 
        warn: winston.warn
    }
});
```

As a bonus, by setting the logger in the same call as `.listen()`, you catch all the log output from Socket.IO.  Note that you should be able to just pass `winston` instead of that object, but it isn't working for me, so that's why I've posted this solution instead.

Comment: how would you do this same thing in express.io (the express / socket.io hybrid)

Comment: @silkcom I have no idea, I've never used it.

Answer (score 1):

Since socket.io v1.0 logger parameter does not longer work.
They switched to [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug)

You may refer to this issue on [how to setup Winston with socket.io](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/239)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply plug in the winston instance as the logger object:

```
var winston = require('winston');

io.set('logger', winston);
```

Comment: I think I've done it this way before, but I definitely cannot get it working now.  I suppose there has been an update to either Socket.IO or Winston that has broken this functionality?